# How to install ROS Noetic on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Raspberry Pi 3 and trying to install ROS Noetic. My search leaded to ROS kinetic/melodic. Is it possible to install ROS noetic on Raspberry Pi 3?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389772/how-to-install-ros-noetic-on-raspberry-pi-3?/) by [msvs](https://answers.ros.org/users/52331/msvs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-11-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-01**:
If you're not against running things in containers, you could just use the Docker images. You would want to make sure your exact cpu arch is supported though (I don't remember whether RPi3 is `armhf` or `arm64`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible to install ROS Noetic on Rpi 3 but you will be limited to `Server` or `Core` version as per [Canonical](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)

> Minimum Requirements: A Raspberry Pi

> 2, 3, 4 or CM3 A microSD card An

> Ubuntu Core image A monitor with an

> HDMI interface An HDMI cable A USB

> keyboard

For ROS Noetic desktop you will need RPi 4.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [msvs](https://answers.ros.org/users/52331/msvs/) on 2021-11-01**:
Thank you. This is helpful.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-01**:
Great. Glad you found it helpful. Kindly accept the answer then.